# Should I and how can I avoid update pulled by Google

Tags: updates, nexus-6

I have Nexus 6 and there was a [news](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/10/google-pulls-march-security-update-nexus-6-breaks-safetynet-android-pay/) that google pulled March 2017 update. I have notification pending saying update is downloaded, click to restart and install. I dont get, how can I avoid this update altogether. Do I have to install this one and get the next update hoping it will fix all things? I am afraid accidentally restarting my phone (due to say low battery) will result installing this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl:dr**

OP's device is on  7.0,  whereas this update is for 7.1.1 as explained [here](http://www.droid-life.com/2017/03/10/nexus-6s-android-7-1-1-march-patch-back-brief-pull/)

Hence, OP needn't be concerned about it and apply pending OTA updates

---

**For those on 7.1.1**

According to [Google is Rolling Back Nexus 6 Devices to Android 7.0 Nougat](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-rolling-back-nexus-6-devices-android-7-nougat/), ( also mentions the problems you linked to ),this update is to *roll back* To 7.0 ,  thus, enabling future OTA updates. It quotes Google manager in a reddit

> There was a recent OTA update for Android 7.0 that is causing confusion for some Nexus 6 users. For those of you that want to guarantee future OTA updates, you will need to get back on the 7.0 supported track. If you are experiencing issues after accepting the 7.0 update, please factory reset your device to help resolve any problems.
>
> For any Nexus 6 users that want to continue flashing/sideloading future builds, you can stay on 7.1.1 and continue to do so.

So, if you are willing to downgrade and get OTA updates in future, You should apply this update or flash manually updates if you want to continue on 7.1.1

As you can see on reddit, this appears to be a *first*, where an update actually downgrades your version !

Comment: A stupid question: What is meant by Google "pulled update"? Is it like that update will be uninstalled by next update? So I have to install this one and subsequent one too?

Comment: According to the link you provided *The update has been removed*, and going by the reddit, You have an update that takes you to 7.0 and thereafter keep getting OTAs

Comment: To clarify further, it means that the update which created a problem had been removed by Google, so there is no question of it being available. What you have now is a different update which will roll your device back to 7.0, . Thereafter, you will continue to get OTA as released but if you don't accept the update **and** are on 7.0.1, you will have to manually flash updates- no more OTA

Comment: In settings, it says I am having Android version "7.0". It also states "February 5, 2017" as "Android security patch level". The update window says "This software update will improve the security of your Nexus 6 with the 2017-03 patches." And this update notification is there in my notification tray for 2-3 weeks as I didnt let it continue to install. Observing all this, it feels that this is the update which is pulled by google afterwards. Are you sure when you said "is a different update which will roll your device back to 7.0"?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. Updates don't get applied just because it is downloaded on your device. There is a verification process that happens between the device and OEM server on the status of device Android only then update happens . For example, if you modify your system then update fails because it does not get approved by server. This is a system followed since Lollipop. So when Google pulled out the OTA, it will not approve installation on your device. You can be sure of that

Comment: I don't have device but I am sure of what I said

Comment: Further, see this - the pulled update was for 7.1 and you are on 7.0, so it can't affect you in any case http://www.droid-life.com/2017/03/10/nexus-6s-android-7-1-1-march-patch-back-brief-pull/